# Task transitions to Canceled even when token does not match thrown OperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, .net

According to Microsofts own [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx), when a task observes an [OperationCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx), it will transition to the Canceled state - but only if the [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) matches the one associated with the task, otherwise it should transition to Faulted just as with any other exception:

> When a task instance observes an OperationCanceledException thrown by user code, it compares the exception's token to its associated token (the one that was passed to the API that created the Task). If they are the same and the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns true, the task interprets this as acknowledging cancellation and transitions to the Canceled state. If you do not use a Wait or WaitAll method to wait for the task, then the task just sets its status to Canceled.
>
> ...
>
> If the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns false or if the exception's token does not match the Task's token, the OperationCanceledException is treated like a normal exception, causing the Task to transition to the Faulted state. Also note that the presence of other exceptions will also cause the Task to transition to the Faulted state. You can get the status of the completed task in the Status property.

This is not what I see in my tests however. If I execute the following code (where [WaitForCompletionStatus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/05/04/10007499.aspx) is from [ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx)):

```
var ctsForTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ctsForExc = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    throw new OperationCanceledException(ctsForExc.Token);
}, ctsForTask.Token);

task.WaitForCompletionStatus();
Console.WriteLine("Status: " + task.Status);
```

and check the console, it prints

```
Status: Canceled
```

Am I missing something or is the Microsoft documentation blatantly wrong on this point?

PS: In fact it seems to be double wrong: it also claims that a check is performed on the tokens IsCancellationRequested property, but in the code I wrote above, none of the tokens are canceled.

Comment: supplying the token to the new exception means it gets assigned as the cancellation token for that task anyway, regardless if there is another token associated with the task, surely ?

Comment: @secretsquirrel Not sure I follow your logic. If the task simply adopted the token from any OCE observed, then the checks mentioned by the Microsoft documentation would be meaningless?

Comment: well, from the link you supplied: If you are waiting on a Task that transitions to the Canceled state...Note that this exception indicates successful cancellation instead of a faulty situation.